# What IDE to use?

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, eclipse, visual-c++

I come from Linux and Windows programming is fairly new to me. On linux, I used to use vim and the command line and everything worked fine, even for large projects. However, on windows, the command line seems a lot more cumbersome and I hear that lots of devs use IDEs. The question is, what do I use (C++ here)? What does everyone usually use? VC++? I've read about Eclipse, how is the C++ support for it? I have used Netbeans for Java and I absolutely love it, is the C++ support upto par? Also, Netbeans seems to need make for windows, which is a pain to set up, is there a good alternative?

Comment: All compilers work just fine from the command-line.  If you don't have a reason to switch IDE, don't.  If you have a particular feature you're looking for, that will help you choose between IDEs.

Comment: Netbeans, in my experience, takes resources when running applications. I usually had (and still do) to run Task Manager to kill NetBeans if it froze on me. Eclipse hasn't given me these problems yet.

Comment: For Windows, Visual C++ 2010 is good and is free to download. http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/ . Its worth giving a try for it.

Comment: In windows I have VS2008 and VS2010, but more often than not --I don't really code anything besides small c++ snippets in windows-- I endup using a console, gvim and cl to compile from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can get an objective answer to a question as general as this.  Different people have different experiences with different IDEs, and opinions are subjective.

My best advice is to be lazy.  If the tools you are used to using do a good (or even half good) job, then don't change.  The real point of an IDE is to get the job done effectively.  Spending lots of time evaluating, setting up, going through the learning curves, switching back and forth doesn't get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are moving to doing development for windows, VC++ is a very good IDE, and arguably the best for pure windows development, I perfer eclipse though, mainly so that I have a single IDE that I use no matter what platform I'm on (Windows, Linux, and Mac).

The C++ support is execlent with the latest eclipse and CDT (C/C++ Development Tools) versions so that shouldn't be much of a problem.

I never have been that happy using Netbeans, but that is personal taste I think.

Comment: Visual Studio is the de facto standard for everything Microsoft I guess.

Comment: @Camilo: Post Borland C++ 4.5, pretty much, although My favorite Dos/Windows IDE was Borlands TurboC++ 3.1 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use Eclipse for Java and love it, have had no problems.  The intellisense is great and the automatic formatting works perfectly.

Currently I am using Visual Studio for C# and C++ but it leaves much to be desired in terms of performance, so I too am looking for a new solution there.

Answer (score 1):

I thought Netbeans used Ant for build scripts, but I could be wrong. It's been a long time.

I use Visual Studio and find it's a fairly nice IDE with decent command line for build scripts, etc.

Comment: for the c++ side it uses a very poor bastardization of ant and make, essentially using ant to call make from what I remember. (last time I used Netbeans was Netbeans 5.0 so its been a while too).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).  It is the IDE I used for C++ to make the transition.  Worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. :-)

Are you moving to Windows "permanently", or just creating a new port? You can continue to use your old tools, if you work on several platforms.

Otherwise, VC++ is the native compiler for Windows. Obviously the one Microsoft uses for compiling Windows itself. The source code debugger is very well integrated with the rest of the IDE, and supports downloading debug info for the system binaries as well. Can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Java irrespective of the OS you are using, I highly recommend [IDEA IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). There is also an open source "Community Edition" now which is quite cool.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you used to use vim and command line in linux u'll find anything in Windows OS is so simple comparing with vim and command line so i thinkmit's so easy for u to convert to any IDE in Windows but i think it's better to use the native IDE for C++ by Microsoft itself not to use any other IDE from any another company because as i think the biggest advantage in Microsoft is its Support for its products and u can find easily tutorials and documentation easily